# Z-indexes not working as expected even positioning is specified

Tags: html, css

here are my codes:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h1 style="color:rgb(153,50,204)" class="visible-sm visible-xs" style="z-index:0; position:relative; "> Descriptions </h1>
                <pre class="pre-scrollable" style="z-index:0;">
In show dull give need so held. One order all scale sense her gay style wrote. Incommode our not one ourselves residence. Shall there whose those stand she end. So unaffected partiality indulgence dispatched to of celebrated remarkably. Unfeeling are had allowance own perceived abilities.

As it so contrasted oh estimating instrument. Size like body some one had. Are conduct viewing boy minutes warrant expense. Tolerably behaviour may admitting daughters offending her ask own. Praise effect wishes change way and any wanted. Lively use looked latter regard had. Do he it part more last in. Merits ye if mr narrow points. Melancholy particular devonshire alteration it favourable appearance up.

Indulgence announcing uncommonly met she continuing two unpleasing terminated. Now busy say down the shed eyes roof paid her. Of shameless collected suspicion existence in. Share walls stuff think but the arise guest. Course suffer to do he sussex it window advice. Yet matter enable misery end extent common men should. Her indulgence but assistance favourable cultivated everything collecting.

Dependent certainty off discovery him his tolerably offending. Ham for attention remainder sometimes additions recommend fat our. Direction has strangers now believing. Respect enjoyed gay far exposed parlors towards. Enjoyment use tolerably dependent listening men. No peculiar in handsome together unlocked do by. Article concern joy anxious did picture sir her. Although desirous not recurred disposed off shy you numerous securing.

Spoke as as other again ye. Hard on to roof he drew. So sell side ye in mr evil. Longer waited mr of nature seemed. Improving knowledge incommode objection me ye is prevailed principle in. Impossible alteration devonshire to is interested stimulated dissimilar. To matter esteem polite do if

                </pre>
```

The other element:

```
<div id="scroll" class="row img-responsive" style="z-index:10; position:relative; margin:0px;background-color:  rgb(123,20,174); background-size:cover; background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;height:10vh;width:100%;">
```

The scroll has a higher z-index, but it is under the other element.

Comment: Can you post a working code example, maybe a codepen?

Comment: If I put your code in a jsfiddle, it works as expected, at least if I put the div a little higher on the screen. Which makes me wonder, what is the effect you're trying to achieve?